# Difference between blocks and arguments in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arguments, objective-c-blocks

In Objective C, if a block can take arguments and return values (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html),

then what's the difference between blocks and arguments?

Comment: A block can have arguments.  A block can also be an argument to a method which takes a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block is just a section of code, thats all.

An argument, or parameter, on the other hand is a value that is passed to a function or a block so the code in that block can use it.

For instance:

```
^(int anIntegerArgument){
    //this is inside of a block
}
```

This whole statement is referred to as a block. The value anIntegerArgument, however, is an argument.

A block *can* be an argument if you need to pass into a method some custom code. For example, in SpriteKit after running an action you can choose to run some code after it completes. To do this, you pass in a block as an argument:

```
[self runAction:anAction completion:^{
     //block run at the end of an action
}];
```

Comment: So whenever I need to use an argument, I can just pass in the argument into a block like your example above?

Comment: yeah, thats exactly how you would pass in a value to a block.